# How to insert an image before each radio button using f:selectItems

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I constructed the radio button group using `f:selectItems`. I constructed the radio button as follows

```
<h:selectOneRadio>
   <f:selectItems value="#{options}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

How to insert an image before every individual radio button in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with standard JSF components. But you could use MyFaces Tomahawk to achieve this. The `<t:selectOneRadio>` component offers `spread` layout. This way you can place each radio button wherever you want. Something like this:

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="mySelectOneRadio" layout="spread">
   <f:selectItems value="#{options}"/>
</t:selectOneRadio>

<h:graphicImage value="/some/image1.png"/>
<t:radio for="mySelectOneRadio" index="0"/>

<h:graphicImage value="/some/image2.png"/>
<t:radio for="mySelectOneRadio" index="1"/>

..
```